# Как вызвать терминал в pyqt приложении и выполнить в нем команду?

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5

Есть десктопное миниприложение под linux с кнопкой:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 # coding=utf-8
 import sys
 from qt import *
 a = QApplication(sys.argv)
 # Наша функция, которая будет вызвана при нажатии на кнопку

 #создание кнопки
 btn = QPushButton("Выполнить",None)
 #назначить обработчик

 a.setMainWidget(btn)
 btn.show()
 a.exec_loop()
```

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывался терминал и в нем выполнялась команда "cd /home"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классный вопрос и оригинальный.Можно сделать с pyautogui:
`pip install pyautogui`
или

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```

```
import os,pyautogui
from time import sleep
os.system("gnome-terminal -e ''")
pyautogui.typewrite("cd /home")
sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite("other command")
sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
sleep(1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, применил! Очень классное решение и универсальное для любых команд в терминале!!!Только после  каждого набора текста нужная задержка time.sleep(1)

Comment: если нужно изменить скорость набора используйте 

`pyautogui.press(buttonName)`
`time.sleep(howMuchToWait)`
`pyautogui.press(nextButton)`
`time.sleep(howMuchToWait)`
`pyautogui.press(nextButton)`

и т.д.
А после команды:
`pyautogui.press("enter")`

Answer (score 1):

Да... закрутил я. Mожно так :

```
import os
os.system(""" gnome-terminal -e 'cd home && read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue..."' """)
```

А все таки эффектнее будет так:

```
import os,pyautogui
from time import sleep
os.system("gnome-terminal -e ''")
pyautogui.typewrite("cd /home")
sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

## **UPDATE:**

Можно использовать appscript( Bероятно кроссплатформенно !)  :

```
pip3 install appscript
```

или `pip install appscript`
Код:

```
import appscript
appscript.app('Terminal').do_script('cd /home')
```

Проверено на макосe.

#### Под Mac Os :

```
import os
os.system(""" osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd /home"' """)
```

#### Под Windows:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["cd /home"], shell=True)
```

Команда cd /home условная .Вместо нее естественно может быть другая.

Comment: У меня Xubuntu 18. Попробовал ваш вариант где одной строкой через os.system. Терминал открывает, но выдает ошибку "Не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок "cd"(нет такого файла или каталога)", хотя я указал правильный путь cd /home

Comment: Надо через && (исправил)!
```os.system(""" gnome-terminal -e 'cd home && read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press any key to continue..."' """)
```